# How are brokerage accounts protected from theft, computer glitches and fraud?

Tags: united-states, investing, brokerage, fraud, identity-theft

I'm thinking about investing in stocks, but I'm worried about losing my investments for reasons unrelated to changes in the market.

I know that brokerage accounts are not FDIC-insured.

- What if a hacker logs in as me, sells my assets and moves the money somewhere?
- What if the brokerage steals from my account?
- What if the brokerage loses assets from my account unintentionally, due to software bugs?
- etc.

What protections are there in place and should I trust them?

Comment: Added location tag. Based on FDIC, I assume you're asking about the US?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A protection similar to FDIC for banks is provided to brokerage accounts' owners by [SIPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Securities_Investor_Protection_Corporation). Neither FDIC nor SIPC provide protection or insurance against identity thefts or frauds, only bank/brokerage failures. Your investment losses are obviously not insured either.

For fraud liability check your bank/brokerage policies, you can get insurance for identity theft from your insurance provider (its an optional coverage with many home-owner/renter insurance policies).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that FDIC does not insure against fraud and theft. Apparently misleading statements are often made about it.